# Music players (except Banshee) capable of saving scrobbles while being offline?

Tags: music, banshee, music-player

I do not have a stable internet connection right now, so I am looking for a native Linux application capable of saving scrobbles while being offline in order to submit them later, at the same time capable of showing tracks I have not yet listened to. I know that this funcionality is present in Banshee, however it has a bug (I'm using Xubuntu 14.04) that does not allow me to do so...perhaps you know a few that do have such a function and can even point me to the specific portion of code that does exactly that?

Answer (score 1):

1. Clementine (sudo apt-get install clementine)
2. Musique Player (sudo apt-get install musique)
3. Amarok (sudo apt-get install amarok)
4. Rythmbox  (sudo apt-get install rhythmbox)
5. VLC (sudo apt-get install VLC)
6. Qmmp (sudo apt-get install qmmp)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Qmmp! Did not know about this one; it has a nice GUI but I have yet to check the scrobbling functionality.